# Syntax Error after upgrading to Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

My tests are failing like so.

```
SyntaxError:
  /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5@myproject/gems/capybara-3.2.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:129: syntax error, unexpected '.'
        @server&.wait_for_pending_requests
```

This happens after I upgraded to Rails 5.2 from 5.0.3. My current Gem file is as following.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
end

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6.0'
    gem 'guard'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem "factory_girl_rails"
    gem 'capybara'
    gem "capybara-webkit"
end
```

can someone help me before I lose all my hairs? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Ruby version `2.2.5` and you are also upgrading `capybara` to version `3.2.1`. If you take a look at the line that causes the syntax error, the commit message give you a hint: [Require minimum of Ruby 2.3.0](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blame/master/lib/capybara/session.rb#L129)

If you look at the [history](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md#changed), `capybara` version `3.2.0` requires Ruby `2.3.0+`.

You can either upgrade your applications Ruby version to `2.3.0` or greater, or set your `capybara` version to a prior version.

Comment: thanks for helping. I have upgraded to ruby 2.5.1. It works.

Comment: awesome glad I could help :)